# Проверка с файлом

Tags: python

Не понимаю в чём собственно проблема когда выполняю программу во время цикла с `введите ваше имя` вылетает ошибка `index out of range`
в `yarint.txt` ничего нету
Код:

```py
elif choose == 'зарегистрироваться' or choose == 'регистрация' or choose == 'register' or choose == 'reg' or choose == 'рег':
    name = input('Введите ваше имя:')
    with open('yarin.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as r:
        import re
        op = len(re.findall(r"[\n']+", open('yarin.txt').read()))
        x = r.readlines()
        read = x[op].strip()
        while op > 0:
            read = x[op].strip()
            op -= 1
            read = x1[op].strip()
            if op == 0 and name != read:
                print('Имя введено успешно!')
                with open('yarin.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as wr:
                    wr.write('\n' + name)
                password = input('Введите желаемый пароль:')
                while len(password) < 7:
                    print('Пароль слишком короткий.')
                    password = input('Введите желаемый пароль:')
                if len(password) > 7:
                    print('Вы успешно ввели пароль!')
                    check1 = open('yarin.txt', 'w')
                    check1.write(password)
                    check1.close()
                    check = input('Подтвердите пароль:')
                    with open('yarin.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as r2:
                        op2 = len(re.findall(r"[\n']+", open('yarin.txt').read()))
                        x2 = r2.readlines()
                        rode = x2[op2].strip()
                        while op2 > 0:
                            rode = x2[op2].strip()
                            op2 -= 1
                            rode = x2[op2].strip()
                            if rode == name:
                               rode = x2[op2].strip()
                               op2 += 1
                               rode = x2[op2].strip()
                               while check != rode:
                                   print('Неверный пароль!')
                                   check = input('Попробуйте ещё раз')
                               if check == rode: 
                                   print(1)
            elif name == read:
                print('Имя уже занято!')
                print('Пройдите регистрацию заново.')
        while len(name) < 7 or len(name) > 16:
            print('Минимально количество символов в нике 7, а максимальное 16.')
            name = input('Введите ваше имя:')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если yarint.txt пуст (надеюсь он и есть yarin.txt), то что вы ожидаете будет в x (который в  x = r.readlines()) и из которого вы пытаетесь что-то достать? Но вообще куда быстрее просто глянуть в стектрейс ошибки, чтобы сразу увидеть строку с проблемой, а потом дойти туда дебагом, чем ожидать ответа. И еще - этот код все равно работать не будет. Какие то непонятные множественные открытия файлов (без закрытия), где перезатираются только что внесенные данные, непонятная логика поиска (как оно вообще должно работать?.) и т.д.

Comment: Ну вот как-то работает, а в  `with ... as` я ошибки не вижу ведь этот цикл автоматически должен закрывать открытый файл. Но я пересмотрю код.

Comment: Ну "как-то" работает. Еще бы работал "как надо", то и вопроса бы не было.  `with..as` закрывает, но у вас в коде закрывает "когда-нибудь потом", а не "когда уже не нужно". Когда открывается `as r2` -  `as r` до сих пор открыт. Сами смотрите - где-то `with..as`, где то `open..close`, где то `encoding="utf-8"`, а где-то нет. Судя по `wr.write('\n' + name)` вы хотите дописать имя файл, но файл открыт на перезапись. Более того, буквально сразу весь файл перезаписывается паролем. `r"[\n']+"` - что за апостроф, зачем он для подсчета количества элементов если подразумевается количество строк? и т.д.